# What does '-c' parameter do in Mahout trainnb commant?

Tags: machine-learning, mahout, bayesian

I cannot understand for what `-c` parameter stands for in this Mahout command, when I am training Naive Bayes model:

```
mahout trainnb -i train-vectors -el -li labelindex -o model -ow -c
```

Does it turn on Complementary naive Bayes algorithm ?

If no, is there any possibility to use it while I am training a model ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [TrainNaiveBayesJob.java](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/mahout/trunk/core/src/main/java/org/apache/mahout/classifier/naivebayes/training/TrainNaiveBayesJob.java) you can see that indeed, it is used to control the use of complementary naive Bayes algorithm, that is disabled by default.